# How to read style information from PSD Programmatically

Tags: adobe-photoshop

We have a base design for a web site which includes different control and thier placement which is mostly constant. Every time we get a new requirement, what we have to do is copy the old design and just change the skin (Font Color, Font Style, Background, ForeColor etc).

Problem is that we get new design in PSD and then we have to fetch skin related information. Is there a way to fetch this information programmatically?

Thanks In Advance,
adjain

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You don't state developer environment so I generalize the answer by pointing you to the API specifications right here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: Development environment is VS 2010.

Comment: It's bedtime for me, but see if this doesn't help you get online: http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/ (a bit old, but shows the basics) and this http://forums.adobe.com/message/3549891